# Javascript filtering by 3 or more values

Tags: javascript, filtering

I'm new to using this site, not sure if I need to edit my original question or if starting a new one is the appropiate way of doing things.

Anyway, I got some help yesterday with filtering using Javascript. Thanks again to those who helped me out. I tried to add another filter (price), along with modifying the javascript, but it's not working. The Color and Size work like they're suppose to, but I wanted to add another category, "price", to also aid in drilling-down the filtering.

1. What I'm trying to do it have the user select one or all the Colors and have those products displayed. If no Color is choosen then display all the products.
   (That is already working)
2. Then when/if they choose a Size or multiple Sizes, only show the products in the Colors from #1 AND the sizes chosen. If no Color is chosen then only show products with the choosen Size.
   (That is already working)
3. Now I'm trying to include another category called Price but I can't get it working. So I'm trying to use #1 and #2 filtering to include a drill-down for price. As an example; if Color and Size is not chosen, then it will only show products with the checked Price. If Green and $20 is chosen, then it will not show any products. If no Color is selected, Medium and Large are selected, and $20 is selected, it will only show Product C.

I hope that clarifies what I'm trying to do. If anyone can help, that would be greatly appreciated!

```js
const filterCheckboxes = document.querySelectorAll('.filter-checkbox');
const colorCheckboxes = document.querySelectorAll('.color-checkbox');
const sizeCheckboxes = document.querySelectorAll('.size-checkbox');
const priceCheckboxes = document.querySelectorAll('.price-checkbox');
const filterables = document.querySelectorAll('.filterable');

function updateFilter() {
  const colorChecked = Array.from(colorCheckboxes)
    .filter(checkbox => checkbox.checked)
    .map(checkbox => checkbox.value);

  const sizeChecked = Array.from(sizeCheckboxes)
    .filter(checkbox => checkbox.checked)
    .map(checkbox => checkbox.value);

  const priceChecked = Array.from(priceCheckboxes)
    .filter(checkbox => checkbox.checked)
    .map(checkbox => checkbox.value);

  if (!(colorChecked.length || sizeChecked.length || priceChecked.length)) {
    filterables.forEach(filterable => {
      filterable.style.display = 'block';
    })
    return;
  }

  filterables.forEach(filterable => {
    const colors = filterable.dataset.colors.split(' ');
    if (colorChecked.length >= 1 && sizeChecked.length >= 1 && priceChecked.length >= 2) {
      if (colorChecked.includes(colors[0]) && sizeChecked.includes(colors[1]) && priceChecked.includes(colors[2])) {
        filterable.style.display = 'block';
      } else {
        filterable.style.display = 'none';
      }
    } else {
      if (colorChecked.includes(colors[0]) || sizeChecked.includes(colors[1]) || priceChecked.includes(colors[2])) {
        filterable.style.display = 'block';
      } else {
        filterable.style.display = 'none';
      }
    }
  });
}

filterCheckboxes.forEach(checkbox => {
  checkbox.addEventListener('change', updateFilter);
});

updateFilter(); // initial filter based on default checkbox state
```

```html
<div>
  <h3>Color</h3>
  <label><input type="checkbox" class="filter-checkbox color-checkbox" value="red">Red</label>
  <label><input type="checkbox" class="filter-checkbox color-checkbox" value="green">Green</label>
  <label><input type="checkbox" class="filter-checkbox color-checkbox" value="blue">Blue</label>
</div>
<div>
  <h3>Size</h3>
  <label><input type="checkbox" class="filter-checkbox size-checkbox" value="small">Small</label>
  <label><input type="checkbox" class="filter-checkbox size-checkbox" value="medium">Medium</label><label>
    <input type="checkbox" class="filter-checkbox size-checkbox" value="large">Large</label>
</div>
<div>
  <h3>Price</h3>
  <label><input type="checkbox" class="filter-checkbox price-checkbox" value="10">$10</label>
  <label><input type="checkbox" class="filter-checkbox price-checkbox" value="20">$20</label><label>
    <input type="checkbox" class="filter-checkbox price-checkbox" value="30">$30</label>
</div>
<div>
  <br>
  <hr>
  <h1>Filtered Result</h1>
  <div class="filterable" data-colors="blue large 30">Product A</div>
  <div class="filterable" data-colors="green small 10">Product B</div>
  <div class="filterable" data-colors="red medium 20">Product C</div>
  <div class="filterable" data-colors="red large 30">Product D</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Hey, I mean filtering. I'm not too worried about sorting. Thanks for the explanation. Updated my post accordingly.

Comment: I have update the code in the answer. Try that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The below code will **filter based on color, size and price**.

- The function **getCheckedValues()** to avoid the **code repetition**.
- The **level** variable is use for getting the **filtering level**. If only **one type of filter** is selected then its **value 1**, if **two type of filters** are selected then its **value 2** and if **all type of filters** are selected then its value is **3**. For example, if you select **red and green color**, it means then you select only **one type of filter that is color**.

```js
const filterCheckboxes = document.querySelectorAll('.filter-checkbox');
const colorCheckboxes = document.querySelectorAll('.color-checkbox');
const sizeCheckboxes = document.querySelectorAll('.size-checkbox');
const priceCheckboxes = document.querySelectorAll('.price-checkbox');
const filterables = document.querySelectorAll('.filterable');

function getCheckedValues(checkboxes) {
  return Array.from(checkboxes)
    .filter(checkbox => checkbox.checked)
    .map(checkbox => checkbox.value);
}

function updateFilter() {
 let level = 0;

 const colorChecked = getCheckedValues(colorCheckboxes);
 // If there is any Color Checkbox
 if (colorChecked.length) level++;

 const sizeChecked = getCheckedValues(sizeCheckboxes);
 // If there is any Size Checkbox
 if (sizeChecked.length) level++;

 const priceChecked = getCheckedValues(priceCheckboxes);
 // If there is any price Checkbox
 if (priceChecked.length) level++;

 if (!level) {
   filterables.forEach(filterable => {
     filterable.style.display = 'block';
   })
   return;
 }

 filterables.forEach(filterable => {
   const colors = filterable.dataset.colors.split(' ');
   switch (level) {
     case 1:
       // if this case, it means that only one filter is selected
       if (colorChecked.includes(colors[0]) || sizeChecked.includes(colors[1]) || priceChecked.includes(colors[2])) {
          filterable.style.display = 'block';
       } else {
          filterable.style.display = 'none';
       }
       break;
     case 3:
       // Case 3 means that all filters are selected
       if (colorChecked.includes(colors[0]) && sizeChecked.includes(colors[1]) && priceChecked.includes(colors[2])) {
          filterable.style.display = 'block';
       } else {
         filterable.style.display = 'none';
       }
       break;
     default:
       // Default means that two filters are seleted
       if (colorChecked.length >= 1 && sizeChecked.length >= 1) {
         if (colorChecked.includes(colors[0]) && sizeChecked.includes(colors[1])) {
            filterable.style.display = 'block';
         } else {
            filterable.style.display = 'none';
         }
        } else if (colorChecked.length >= 1 && priceChecked.length >= 1) {
           if (colorChecked.includes(colors[0]) && priceChecked.includes(colors[2])) {
                filterable.style.display = 'block';
           } else {
                filterable.style.display = 'none';
           }
         } else {
           if (sizeChecked.includes(colors[1]) && priceChecked.includes(colors[2])) {
              filterable.style.display = 'block';
            } else {
                filterable.style.display = 'none';
            }
          }
          break;
        }
      });
}

filterCheckboxes.forEach(checkbox => {
   checkbox.addEventListener('change', updateFilter);
});

updateFilter(); // initial filter based on default checkbox state
```

```html
<div>
    <h3>Color</h3>
    <label><input type="checkbox" class="filter-checkbox color-checkbox" value="red">Red</label>
    <label><input type="checkbox" class="filter-checkbox color-checkbox" value="green">Green</label>
    <label><input type="checkbox" class="filter-checkbox color-checkbox" value="blue">Blue</label>
  </div>
  <div>
    <h3>Size</h3>
    <label><input type="checkbox" class="filter-checkbox size-checkbox" value="small">Small</label>
    <label><input type="checkbox" class="filter-checkbox size-checkbox" value="medium">Medium</label><label>
      <input type="checkbox" class="filter-checkbox size-checkbox" value="large">Large</label>
  </div>
  <div>
    <h3>Price</h3>
    <label><input type="checkbox" class="filter-checkbox price-checkbox" value="10">$10</label>
    <label><input type="checkbox" class="filter-checkbox price-checkbox" value="20">$20</label><label>
      <input type="checkbox" class="filter-checkbox price-checkbox" value="30">$30</label>
  </div>
  <div>
    <br>
    <hr>
    <h1>Filtered Result</h1>
    <div class="filterable" data-colors="blue large 30">Product A</div>
    <div class="filterable" data-colors="green small 10">Product B</div>
    <div class="filterable" data-colors="red medium 20">Product C</div>
    <div class="filterable" data-colors="red large 30">Product D</div>
  </div>
```

Comment: I appreciate you commenting out the code too.

Answer (score 0):

Note I delegate from the nearest static container. Here I wrapped the filters in a div

I partly based to code on the comments given. You can update your question with the comments.

```js
const filterKeys = ["color", "size", "price"],
  filterObjectString = JSON.stringify(filterKeys.reduce((acc, key) => (acc[key] = [], acc), {})),
  filterables = document.querySelectorAll('.filterable');

const comparable = (filter, foundProps) => {
  return filterKeys.every(key => { // each filter key is tested 
    const filterValues = filter[key];
    const foundValue = foundProps[key]?.[0]; // found any for key?
    // either we are not filtering for that prop OR the prop has to be in the list of filtervalues
    return filterValues.length === 0 || (foundValue && filterValues.includes(foundValue));
  });
};
const updateFilter = () => {
  const checkedFilters = document.querySelectorAll('.filter-checkbox:checked');
  if (checkedFilters.length === 0) { // no need to process
    filterables.forEach(filterable => filterable.hidden = false);
    return;
  }
  
  // group the values of the checked filter checkboxes
  const selectedFilters = [...checkedFilters]
    .reduce((acc, cur) => {
      filterKeys.forEach(key => {
        if (cur.classList.contains(`${key}-checkbox`)) acc[key].push(cur.value);
      });
      return acc;
    }, JSON.parse(filterObjectString)); // use a new copy each time

  // filter the items
  filterables.forEach(filterable => {
    const props = filterable.dataset.properties.split(' ');
    const foundProps = props.reduce((acc, prop, i) => {
      const key = filterKeys[i];
      const selFilter = selectedFilters[key];
      if (selFilter.includes(prop))(acc[key] ??= []).push(prop); // conditional assignment
      return acc;
    }, {});
    filterable.hidden = !comparable(selectedFilters, foundProps)
  });
};

document.getElementById("filterDiv").addEventListener("click", updateFilter);
updateFilter(); // initial filter based on default checkbox states
```

```css
#filterDiv {
  display: flex
}

#filterDiv div {
  border: 1px solid black;
  padding: 5px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}
```

```html
<div id="filterDiv">
  <div>
    <h3>Color</h3>
    <label><input type="checkbox" class="filter-checkbox color-checkbox" value="red">Red</label>
    <label><input type="checkbox" class="filter-checkbox color-checkbox" value="green">Green</label>
    <label><input type="checkbox" class="filter-checkbox color-checkbox" value="blue">Blue</label>
  </div>
  <div>
    <h3>Size</h3>
    <label><input type="checkbox" class="filter-checkbox size-checkbox" value="small">Small</label>
    <label><input type="checkbox" class="filter-checkbox size-checkbox" value="medium">Medium</label><label>
    <input type="checkbox" class="filter-checkbox size-checkbox" value="large">Large</label>
  </div>
  <div>
    <h3>Price</h3>
    <label><input type="checkbox" class="filter-checkbox price-checkbox" value="10">$10</label>
    <label><input type="checkbox" class="filter-checkbox price-checkbox" value="20">$20</label><label>
    <input type="checkbox" class="filter-checkbox price-checkbox" value="30">$30</label>
  </div>
</div>
<div>
  <br>
  <hr>
  <h1>Filtered Result</h1>
  <div class="filterable" data-properties="blue large 30">Product A blue large 30</div>
  <div class="filterable" data-properties="green small 10">Product B green small 10</div>
  <div class="filterable" data-properties="red medium 20">Product C red medium 20</div>
  <div class="filterable" data-properties="red large 30">Product D red large 30</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Please note `every` only shows the elements that matches ALL filters. `some` matches any element that contains a checked filter

Comment: Thanks for the note. I'm still learning Javascript, so your solution is very helpful.

Comment: Is there a way to do both 'every' and 'some'? For example; I'd like to use 'some' for the color, that way if Red and Green are selected it shows both of those options. Then if Medium is selected, it only shows if medium is included from the first filter of Red and Green. Or some way in which if only one div section has been checked (color for example), it uses 'some'. But if two or more div sections are selected (Color AND Size), then it uses 'every'.

Comment: @AdamZ this answer is not right. I answered you yesterday. And your requirement was that:- let say if you select red color then all red color items should show. and if you then select medium as a size, then only those items show that are red and also medium in size. This was your yesterday requirement. And this answer is doing that what you was already doing yesterday in your question. Please test it. this is not giving the right results. If you agree, then tell me. I can answer it with another filter also.

Comment: @Developer Your answer yesterday was very helpful, thanks again for that. I was having some trouble getting another category added to the code you helped me with. So that's the reason why I posted my question today. But you're correct, his answer isn't exactly the solution I need. I'm not trying to step on any toes here, just trying to understand scripting better and get help for a solution. If you don't mind and have time, please take a look at my post above and let me know what I'm missing.

Comment: @AdamZ101 don't worry. I am writing an answer for your post with explanation. Just wait

Comment: @mplungjan This is not what OP need.

Comment: @Developer I believe it is now working as expected

Comment: @AdamZ101 I fixed the logic. I was not near a computer for a while

Comment: @Developer Maybe you can help me with adding another category? I asked another question on here with where I'm at with my code.

Comment: I will not try to fix someone else's code when I have my own

Comment: @AdamZ101 send the link where you asked

Comment: @Developer Just click the name and then questions